# No UDP pipeline in netty 4

Tags: netty

Hi I am using netty 4 example (qotm) to create a UDP server where 'Bootstrap' is used.  This class does not allow pipeline the handlers.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I ended up implement my own io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.ChannelFactory so that I can add my own pipeline into the Channel

Answer (score 5):

You can specify a `ChannelInitializer` for `Bootstrap.handler(..)`, just like other examples with multiple handlers in a pipeline.

Please keep in mind that UDP is connectionless and thus a UDP channel handles all packets from multiple remote hosts using a *single* pipeline.  To set up different pipeline for different protocols, you must create multiple UDP channels and bind them on different ports, just like you did in Netty 3.

Comment: In netty 3, if i change the pipeline of the upd channel post creation, it would affect *all* incoming udp traffic. Is the same true for Netty 4. Is there a way to define protocol per udp channel?

Comment: Norman has provided this solution in another Q. Might be helpful to others who need it to be on same port. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336672/netty-different-pipeline-per-udp-datagram